# How to store multiple base64 values to array?

Tags: javascript, html

Please take a look at my jsFiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/vedt_/zrvuwbj7/59/

So far, I have it so that when the image is uploaded, it is converted into base64 format and then stored in localStorage. However, I want it to be when every time someone enters an image into the input field, each input is pushed in an array and the values of that array can be called whenever needed. How do I do this?

**JavaScript Code**

```js
var array = []

function myFunction() {
     const file = document.querySelector('#uploadImage').files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = function () {
     localStorage.setItem("image", reader.result);
     document.getElementById("imagePreview").setAttribute("src", localStorage.getItem("image"))
     };
}
if(localStorage.getItem("image"))
     document.getElementById("imagePreview").setAttribute("src", localStorage.getItem("image"))
   
function clr() {
 localStorage.clear()
 location.reload()
}
```

```css
img {
 max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="uploadImage"><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit Picture</button><br>
<button onclick="clr()">Clear LocalStorage</button>
<img id="imagePreview">
```

Again, I would like it so that every time the user presses the submit button, the value of the image is converted into the base 64 image and pushed into an array which can later be stored into the localStorage. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Store JavaScript arrays to localStorage in JSON format:

```
localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(myImages));
```

Retrieve JSON from localStorage and convert back to array:

```
let myImages = [];
myImages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images"));
```

But as a comment mentions below, there is a 5MB limit for localStorage, so a better storage method might be IndexedDB, which has a higher limit.

Comment: I was asking something different.

Comment: not a good solution to store in localStorage which has a broswer limit of 5Mb

Comment: @hiphopfeels Please describe, then, where you are stuck. Do you not how how to push onto an array?

Comment: Please look at my code. I don't know how to push the value of event.target.result into an array to store into localStorage.

Comment: `myArray.push(event.target.result)` will do what you want.

Comment: If that didn't work, you have something else wrong. `Array.prototype.push()` simply works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push